# Erdős-Kac and moments

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers, analytic-number-theory

One way to prove  Erdős-Kac is by proving that for each non-negative integer $k$, the $k$-th moment
$$M_k(x):=
\frac{1}{x}\sum_{1 \leq n \leq x} \left(\frac{\omega(n)-\log \log x}{\sqrt{\log \log x}}\right)^k
$$ converges as $x\to+\infty$ to the $k$-th moment of the standard normal distribution.

I was wondering whether the following weak converse is true, i.e. given
the Erdős-Kac theorem can we prove that $M_k(x)=O_k(1)$ without number theory arguments?

Comment: It is known that the characteristic function converges pointwise to Gaussian.